# How to open another window within Main Window in WPF in Tab Control Content in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have used Tab Panel in WPF
in which i have taken 4 Tab Controls,
I want to open 1 window in every single tab (1 window per tab).
I am finding solution for this from 2 days.
But , i didn't get any proper solution.
Please, can anybody tell me it's Solution.

Comment: 4 TabControls or 4 TabItems ? https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/tabcontrol/ start here

Comment: (1) please show what you already have (2) a `Window` within a `TabControl` or `TabItem` doesn't make sense, maybe you used the wrong term? Please explain.

Comment: If you use mvvm you could look at how to implement a WindowService. Just google that

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `Window` in any other container. Use a `UserControl` instead.